# STS randomly resets my PC on Linux Mint 18 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: spring-tool-suite, linux-mint, ubuntu-16.04

STS randomly resets my PC, so I do not get any error or some indications why it is happening.

Until now it happened on:

- Calling Content Assistant
- Creating New Project
- Opening Project
- Deleting Project
- Creating New File

Sometimes it corrupts workspace's .metadata folder structure and every attempt to load that workspace results in imidiate PC reset.

Already tried:

- Fresh instalation of Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon
- Fresh STS and workspace
- Using SWT_GTK3=0
- Using STS 3.8.0 vs 3.8.1

Is there any way to get some useful info on what is causing this?

Comment: With reset, you mean a full reboot without any proper shutdown? To me it sounds like a hardware issue. Could you run some other CPU/RAM intensive programs (3D games?) to reproduce this?

Comment: Yes complete PC reset like turn off. On Windows I used "HeavyLoad" for testing temperatures before without any problems. PC normally  works for days without any problem. I will look for some Linux intensive benchmark program, do you have some suggestion? And only game I usually, but rarely, play is Moded Minecraft and never had any problem with it.

Comment: Hm. Issues like these are hard to debug. Maybe do a file system check (fsck)? I think StackOverflow is the wrong site for that, by the way :)

Comment: That day I did CPU, GPU, RAM, HDD HeavyLoad stress test for 4 hours and SMART Extended test, all green. Then I was away for 4 days and interestingly enough STS is working fine since I came back. No clue why was that happening before but I can finally continue learning Spring. I really hope it will not happen again. Thanks for your time C-Otto, best regards.